# jQuery Waypoints Tutorial

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have included jQuery and Waypoints, I can see both scripts included inside the inspector.

With that being said, I'm not sure at all why my waypoints are not firing. I am just trying to set up a basic alert, where when the element is on screen it fires an alert telling the user so. This is just my proof of concept, and I can't even get that to work. My HTML and JS code is as follows. I can't figure out whats wrong.

-HTML-

```
<div id="coming-soon" class="info-section" >
<div class="happy-cog"></div>
<h2>Features Coming Soon</h2>   
    <div class="coming-soon-features" style="width:100%; ">
        <h3>Coming Soon Div</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

-JS-

```
$(function() {                     // When the page has loaded,
$('#coming-soon').waypoint(               // create a waypoint
    function() {
        alert("Waypoint reached.");
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you put the waypoint right? http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/fqeAe/ (note that this fires when the element reaches the TOP of the viewport)

Comment: Interesting that it works there. I do not have a top set, that could be the potential culprit. I will have a play with it and see if I can figure it out

Comment: @user2172218 Do you get any errors in the console when you load the page? Maybe something like... `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'waypoint' `? Otherwise, you need to be able to scroll some... so if it is just at the top of the page (with no content to scroll to), the event wont fire.

Comment: Ok I see what the problem is. You were right. There is a JS error inside of another script I have running. When I remove that script some functionality doesnt work, but waypoints does work.

The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

It's inside of a js file that allows for smooth scrolling with jQuery. Could it be because I do not have a top set in the css?

Comment: Ok, I resolved the issue. The problem was I have a single page site, with a navigation including hash-tag jump links. I had links in the navigation that were jumping to somewhere that has not yet been defined. Adding a point for the links to jump too removed this error from the javascript. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: When someone 'answers' the question I will mark it as resolved

Comment: never mind I was able to resolve this as well.

Comment: You can answer your own question, you know.